# Bottom positioning of multiple buttons in a list-item

Tags: html, css

I need to create a list-item structure which contains three buttons starts at bottom. What styles are required to place these buttons as displayed in the pic (The sequence of buttons doesn't matter, I just want to place 3 buttons at bottom).

Below is my CSS and HTML.

```css
li{
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden!important;
    text-align:center;
}

.btn-custom{
 
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
       <button type="button" class="btn-custom">Button-3</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn-custom">Button-2</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn-custom">Button-1</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: Play with margin top and margin bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that?

```css
li{
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden!important;
    text-align:center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
       <button type="button" class="btn-custom">Button-3</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn-custom">Button-2</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn-custom">Button-1</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

More info on flexbox [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp), including browser support.

Comment: Thanks wasthishelpful for great solution. You are really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use `display: table-cell` to be able to vertically align content

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.btn-custom{
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <button type="button" class="btn-custom">Button-3</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-custom">Button-2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-custom">Button-1</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Pol for your response. This too works perfectly but wasthishelpful's solution looks better and small for me. And the reference he provided helped me a lot in understanding.